# How do I troubleshoot desktop crashes on 21.04?

Tags: login-screen, 21.04

I am bumping into desktop crashes (called login loop by many) on Ubuntu 21.04.

This started happening after an interrupted `sudo apt install...` session which had run 70 (very low bandwidth) hours before power outage.

Upon power restoration, I reran `apt` thinking the machine would be very out-of-sorts. Notably, `apt` proceeded based, I'm guessing, on its cache. It ran for additional time, then gave me a report which listed 9 or 10 failed packages; there were many lines preceding the failed package which seemed to indicate successful installation of the remaining packages.

After a few more invocations of `apt` to install the failed packages, I was relieved.

Upon rebooting, however, I was met with the desktop crash.

An answer by *user10489*  to this related question ([Recurring problems with Login Loops ubuntu 20.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336511/recurring-problems-with-login-loops-ubuntu-20-10)) was very thorough.

Except for the gnome-specific steps, I examined all the others. None applied.

The problem began after running the completion of apt. I don't recall whether apt prompted me to do so, but I rebooted the machine.

First on my main account... then attempting to login on my backup account (which I always create for cases just like this), leads to the same result.

**SYMPTOMS**
When I press the last key of my password followed by enter, it proceeds as usual... Then the screen turns black, flashes a couple lines of text at top, then returns to login screen and beeps.

Lines flashed on screen:

```
[  133.715541] netdata[4213]: 2021-08-30 11:50:14: netdata INFO  : MAIN : CONFIG: cannot load cloud config '/var/lib/netdata/cloud.d/cloud.conf'. Running with internal defaults.

[   134.569325] netdata[4213]: 2021-08-30 11:50:15: netdata INFO : MAIN : SIGNAL :  Not enabling reaper
```

I am able to access the text terminals.

I created a new user... and faced the same fate.

I examined the `.xsession-errors` resource which consists of 131 lines.

*Among the first ten lines:*

```
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/30x11-common_xresources: line 16: has_option: command not found

/etc/X11/Xsession.d/75dbus_dbus-launch: line 9: has_option: command not found

/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90x11-common_ssh-agent: line 9: has_option: command not found
```

*The last 11 lines*

```
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting _=/usr/bin/dbus-update-activation-environment

dbus-update-activation-environment: warning: error sending to systemd: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs:  Invalid environment assignments

Insecure $ENV{ENV} while running with -T switch at /usr/share/perl5/GnuPG/Interface.pm line 348.

Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/monkeysphere-validation-agent line 22

BEGIN failed--compilation aborted-at /usr/bin/monkeysphere-validation-agent line 22

Use of uninitialized value $line in pattern match (m//) /usr/share/perl5/GnuPG/Interface.pm line 820.

Use of uninitialized value $a in split at /usr/share/perl5/GnuPG/Interface.pm line 834.

Use of uninitialized value $a in split at /usr/share/perl5/GnuPG/Interface.pm line 834.

GnuPG version 1.4 or 2.2+ required at (eval 191) line 55.

Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/monkeysphere-validation-agent line 22.

BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/monkeysphere-validation-agent line 22.
```

Nearly all of the remaining 100 lines in `.xsession-errors` appear to be simple log messages; none have "warning" or "error" but almost all of them relate to dbus.

My instinct is saying there's a problem with the dbus installation.  On the other hand, the messages presented on the screen during the attempted logins have netdata indicated.

But I'm in a strange territory. I'm not sure what to try next. Is it dbus, netdata or something altogether different?

(UPDATE: after looking into netdata, `man` says it's "real-time performance monitoring." So, I highly doubt this is the problem, leaving me with dbus as my only option. It makes sense since system inter-process messaging relies on it.)

Looking in the `/var/crash` directory yields no help. I reviewed the directory. Tried login. Returned to review the `/var/crash` and no new file had been created.

A review of previous crash files were only 2 or 3 lines and had to do with autojack. (Which makes me happy to find because I lost sounds a couple weeks ago... Now, I have a lead!)

(Updated 2021-09-08)
As I continue investigating, I have found `systemctl status` reports "degraded." Upon review of the output from `sustemctl --all list-units` , I see that there are a number (38) of units 'not-found', 5 identified as "masked" and 3 marked as "failed."

Comment: Remember there are two so try `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i <searchword>` and then `cat /var/log/syslog.1 | grep -i <searchword>`

Comment: This system does not have both. I suppose it's an either/or scenario... It's a file; I'll go fishing...

Comment: Hello. Have you checked if the root was mounted as read only?

Comment: I'm researching how to do that... Thanks for the pointer...